# Update model From Database | Visual Studio 2019

Tags: mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

I need to add a new field in the database model.

I am trying to update a data model in `.edmx` file from the database.

**Tried:**

=> Removing the `.edmx` file and adding a new `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` containing `EF Designer from database`.

The wizard then asks for DB details and I checked Database in server explorer and the new field exist and database is connected. But still, the wizard closes without asking about the tables.

=> By selecting `Update model from database` but it showing me the same problem. The wizard close after selecting the MySql Database connection and database.

Below is the image of the wizard before it closes automatically.

**Checked:**

1. Using 'Mysql.Data.Entity.EF6' and not `Mysql.Data.Entities`
2. The version of 'Mysql.Data.Entity.EF6' and 'Mysql.Data' is same.
3. And more from StackOverflow's available solutions but none work.

Can anyone help me with updating the database model from the database? I have to add a new field in a table and update the models accordingly.

[image]

Comment: Why did you not use code first migration?

Comment: Did you check the model to see that the new field is there?

Comment: Ofc.. i Checked..its not there and not even adding ... but its in the database ...And I can't try code first migration because I Already have a dataset on which I have to just add a new field... For every new field I just can't do code first migration.. there has to be something to update the field

Comment: What version of Visual Studio, MySQL for VS, MySQL Connector?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error.

Comment: How could you have the right versions if the latest connector is for VS 2017?

Comment: Because I am having the same issue in VS 2017....

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this error

Installed the latest "MySQL for Visual Studio" even though this screen says 2017 and 2019

[image]

I tried the connector from Oracle's download page and got this

[image]

With the connector from NuGet, I get your error when the wizard just closes (crashes I guess) without error

Comment: But i have the right versions installed... as you can see in the screenshot above... its not giving me any errors... its just closing

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to update model from Database in Visual Studio 2019 using these versions:

```
MySQL Connector Net 8.0.21
MySQL for Visual Studio 2.0.5
```

MySQL for Visual Studio installed **after** MySQL Connector.
Tell me if this works for you!